# While True loop formulation using class and xpath, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, while-loop

I want to check all boxes and flip through pages using looping. Checklist object contains all checkboxes to tick. I flip through pages whil next button's class ="ng-scope". This class will change when I reach the last page to class="ng-scope disabled". I'm not sure how to correctly formulate the condition in the while loop...

```
checklist = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@ng-model="formData[child.id]"]')

nextbtn = webD.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
nextbtncond = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Next")]/parent[@class="ng-scope"]')
nextbtnbreak = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/parent[@class="ng-scope disabled"]')


while nextbtncond == True:
      
   for elem in checklist:
      elem.click()

      webD.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()

   else

      for elem in checklist:
         elem.click()

         webD.find_element_by_link_text('Apply').click()

      break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

checklist = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@ng-model="formData[child.id]"]')
while True:
    for elem in checklist:
        elem.click()
    try:
        WebDriverWait(webD, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[not(contains(@class, "disabled"))]/a[.="Next"]'))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        webD.find_element_by_link_text('Apply').click()
        break
```

With this code you'll click on Next button until `"disabled"` class name not added

Comment: Thanks ! Could you explain how this works? I'm not familiar with this intuition. tThank you

Comment: @RyeRye I've just used ExplicitWait. You can get doc of how to use it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: I meant the try and except :)

Comment: @RyeRye oh..) Exception handling is very important in Python. You can check simple explanation of how it works [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)